# phablet-flash: Installation is taking too long

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I've been trying to flash Ubuntu Touch to a Nexus 4, following [the instructions on this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install).

I'm Running this command:

```
phablet-flash ubuntu-system --channel devel --no-backup
```

...And after doing whatever it needs to do, I get this message:

```
INFO:phablet-flash:Waiting for install to finish on device. Please do not unplug device until phablet-flash finishes.
```

But after waiting for quite some time I get this error:

```
ERROR:phablet-flash:Installation is taking too long or an error occured along the way.
```

I can't find any way to tell the process to spend even more time. Can anyone help me get past this error?

**Update Sep. 30th**

I tried switching on the phone, despite the error, and it actually looked like the flashing succeeded. Everything seemed to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
 phablet-flash ubuntu-system -d mako -b --pending
```

Should put you there. Nexus shouldn't need any `--channel devel`

Comment: Are you sure about that? [According to the guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Step_4_-_Downloading_.26_Deploying_Image_to_Device), `cdimage-touch` is deprecated.

Comment: Your right there was an update http://ubuntu-discourse.org/t/system-images-now-the-recommended-way-to-deploy-and-update-ubuntu-touch/1008